# How can I search "c-- language" in google?

Tags: google-search

How can I search "c-- language" in google?
How does google deal with these kind of special characters?

Answer (score 1):

For this particular language you can generally find results by searching for ["c minus minus"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+minus+minus) or ["c minus minus programming language"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+minus+minus+programming+language).

Their site is at http://www.cminusminus.org/.

Using the word "minus" isn't a general solution, but for C-- in particular many sites have been search optimized for "c minus minus" for this reason, e.g. Stackoverflow's [c-minus-minus tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus).